# GWT editor onPropertyChange

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

How do I use ValueAwareEditor.onPropertyChange? Is this feature implemented already?
It is not being called when editor property changes.

Also I don't see if this method is being called anywhere in the GWT code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems both implementers (`OptionalFieldEditor` and `ListEditor`) currently offers an empty override for this method, so apparently no - this feature is not implemented yet.