# When is "onPropertyChange" called for ValueAwareEditors in the GWT editor framework?

Tags: gwt

A ValueAwareEditor has a method `void onPropertyChange(java.lang.String... paths)`, about which the javadoc says: "Notifies the Editor that one or more value properties have changed."

When exactly is this method called? Is it the duty of the EditorDriver to call this method? Or do I have to implement code that calls this method myself?

Or is it simply not implemented yet at all, which is suggested by this question: [GWT editor onPropertyChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062207/gwt-editor-onpropertychange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is never ever called by the two built-in editor drivers (`git grep onPropertyChange` returns only method declarations), so I guess we can say that this is "simply not implemented yet at all".

Note that `EditorDelegate#subscribe()` is implemented in `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` using the alternate approach to comunicating change: it'll listen to `EntityProxyChange` events and will `RequestFactory#find()` the proxy back when changed, and then update the editor in-place, notifying `ValueAwareEditor`s and `LeafValueEditor`s *via* their `setValue()`.
`subscribe()` is a no-op for the `SimpleBeanEditorDriver`.

Comment: Didn't know about the combination of git and grep, will save me a lot of time in the future.

Comment: That RequestFactoryEditorDriver simply calls setValue (and does not notify the editor beforehand via onPropertyChange, for example) is a pity because it does not seem to allow to warn the user of entity proxy changes while they are editing. At least as long the setValue methods are not overwritten (which seems tedious), the user edited values will simply be overwritten without prior warning.